# I am trying to check for duplicate(s) in console log

Tags: javascript, console, duplicates, console.log

I am making a website that allows teachers to input student names and marks and store them. I have made use of two array's for this which store's name and score in each. I have been informed that when a duplicate value is entered i have to alert the user. I am trying to figure out how to stop this from happening/being added to the console. I am also wondering if there is an effective way that I could check the console for duplicate names and scores. Any help would be great! My function for this is bellow: The else is where I'm trying to make something happen but I am unsure as to how I'd go about this.

```
function add(){
    name.push(nameInput.value);
    mark.push(markInput.value);

    if (name == "" && mark == ""){

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No name or mark Has Been Entered. Please Try Again!";

    } else if (name && mark){


        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Name & Mark has successfully been entered!";
        console.log(name, mark);


    }  else (name && mark || name && mark);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "This name and mark has already been entered";
            console.log("")





    }



    document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener("click", add);
```

Comment: you could simply use array.includes("value") to check if the value is already in array

Comment: does this method work if no values are stored in the array's [ ] ?

Comment: yes it will work even if array is empty..